# delay in the running of a defined function under success function of Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want 
In my HTML page i have put a [input](/questions/tagged/input) tag as 'user name' and a [label](/questions/tagged/label) tag as result . I want to show the situation of availability of this user name for the registering process in the [label](/questions/tagged/label) tag. I searched and found a food code for this purpose.every thing is good with this code but there is one problem.In this code,if the length of entered user name is greater than 3 then the AJAX will run and the situation of availability of this user name will shown in the [label](/questions/tagged/label) tag.the problem is that there is 6 second delay since the start of AJAX to showing the situation in the label.This delay is just for the first running of AJAX and after that everything will be normal. 
my HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("txtUserName").onkeyup = function () {               
                    var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value
                    if (userName.length >= 3) {
                        jQuery.ajax(
                            {
                                url: 'RegisterationService.asmx/UserNameExists',
                                method: 'post',
                                data: { userName: userName },
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var divElement = document.getElementById('label')
                                    if (data.UserNameInUse) {
                                        document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = userName + ' is in Used'
                                        document.getElementById('label').style.color = 'red'
                                        document.getElementById("txtUserName").style.borderColor = "red"
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = userName + ' is available'
                                        document.getElementById('label').style.color = 'green'
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (err) {
                                    alert(err);
                                }
                            });
                    }
            }            
        });        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txtUserName" style="width:50%" type="text" />
    <br />
    <div style="height:30px; width:50%;">
        <label id="label" ></label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AJAX will contact the server, so network delay will influence how long it takes for the answer to arrive. If only the first time takes 6 seconds and then it doesn't look at either the caching settings and if you're not loading a cached response the second time. Also profile the response time of the asmx service you're contacting. Maybe it has to spawn an instance the first time or something, causing delays.

Comment: I think you would want to count a number of seconds between the last key pressed before sending the ajax call. This would prevent the ajax call while the user is still typeing.

Answer (score 1):

Open the page in 2 browsers real quick (ie. Chrome and Firefox), make sure both pages are "fresh".

Now in one of them run your typing test. Takes 6 seconds, right?

Immediately test in the second browser, still takes 6 seconds?

My guess is that the second time, it was fast. Likely due to the reasons Shilly mentioned (caching, server spinning up). If it's still slow, you may have a session startup delay on the server that initializes the user when they authenticate and/or authorize to the endpoint. This might go to a database, pull from a local Active Directory, etc. If that's the case, see if there's something funky going on with that authentication process. 6 seconds is really long.

Also, as Juan mentioned, you should add something called "debounce" to your input, so it only fires an ajax request when the user stops typing for a set amount of time (e.g. 0.5 seconds). [This library will help](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce).

Comment: thanks chad , i checked it on firefox and chrome , the delay is increased to 8 second! but i say again , the delay is just for the first time i open the page , even if i refresh the page the delay is decreased to less than 0.5 second.